# Amazon LexBot slot elicition error while I am switching to intent instead of Elicition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am creating a Lexbot with slot elicition and intent switching. I am trying to swith to specific intent on condition, But it gives me an error related to elicition. while I am not doing any elicition. instead I am switching to intent.

the error message that I am getting is below:

```
'ElicitSlot' next step at 'InitialResponse:CodeHook:Success' in intent 'VPN' contains invalid slotToElicit setting. slotToElicit must be a required Slot within the intent. Change the slot name in slotToElicit and try your request again.
```

Here is the picture:
[In this picture You can see I am switching to intent "TalkToAgent"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klpLn.png)

PS: I am not using any Lambda.

thanks in Advance, guys

I am creating a Lexbot with slot elicition and intent switching. I am trying to swith to specific intent on condition, But it gives me an error related to elicition. while I am not doing any elicition. instead I am switching to intent.